# Custom website search through Google

Tags: google-search

I often search the Matlab website for answers to Matlab questions, but built in search is terrible, so I use google instead. In order to use Google to search Matlab for answers, I have to type "matlab 'whatever question'." I would like to eliminate having to type matlab before every search through Google. Is there a way to search matlab.com with minimal browser clicks and minimal typing?

Comment: Questions about the this site should be posted on [meta], by the other side, yes, questions about Google, the search engine, are welcome. Please checkout [ask] and [tag:google-search].

Comment: How are you searching the matlab.com site?`http://www.google.com/search?q=site:matlab.com` returns only 2 results to me. `www.matlab.com` redirects to `www.mathworks.com/products/matlab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Set the Google Search Results as your homepage on your browser or use custom search engine.

## Explanation

Google Search results pages use URL parameters to pass keywords, filters and some other search options, so you you find a search results pages that that could work as the desired start point to refine your searches you could save that URL. The common ways to do this are to set the desired URL as your browser homepage or bookmark it.

By the other hand, you could create a custom search engine.
Some web browsers like Google Chrome allow users to create custom search engines also you could use [Google Custom Search](http://cse.google.com).

## References

- [Set your default search engine](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?hl=en)